# Hibernate 5 with Spring JTA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jta, atomikos, hibernate-5.x

I am using:

- Hibernate 5.0.2
- Spring 4.2
- Atomikos 3.9.3

The official documentation says you only have to set the jtaTransactionManager, and everything works:

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="atomikosDataSource" />
            <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="jtaTransactionManager"/>
            [...]
    </bean>
```

Unfortuntely, the session is not flushed - no writes are taking place. What is the issue?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that Hibernate 5 requires us to set the following property, which Spring doesn't do automatically yet:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    [...]
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            [...]
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class">jta</prop>
        </props>
```

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I had a different issue. Session was being flushed but the connection was never released. Setting this property resolved my connection leakage issue.

Comment: What is jta value in coordinator class. are we not required to define the factory_class anymore

Comment: Just wanted to give credit to Jason B for his comment above and perhaps add some search words to help other users who have a problem of losing conenctions... We had a problem of losing conenctions. We ran a job that rapidly obtained conenctions and did not release the connections. We tried several ways of configuration until i hit Jason's comment above and that solved our issue.

Comment: This did it for me. Thank you kind stranger!